# SD виртуальный адаптер

Tags: linux, железо

Имеется фотоаппарат, предполагается через [sd удлинитель](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/TF-to-micro-SD-card-Flex-Extension-cable-Extender-Adapter-reader-car-GPS-mobile-25CM-48CM/32783592918.html?spm=a2g0v.search0302.3.252.11ae3052tlYnsS&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0_10152_10151_10613_10615_10614_10059_10314_10534_10084_100031_10083_10307_10604_10606_10607_10341_10065_10142_10340_10068_10343_10342_10125_10301_10543_10103_10344,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=27a519b3-83f6-4dae-9e86-02adf682d03a&algo_expid=27a519b3-83f6-4dae-9e86-02adf682d03a-32) вывести выход и подключиться к ПК, на нём создать виртуальный накопитель и транслировать запись напрямую в компьютер. При наполнении виртуальной карты памяти создаётся новая, а из старой данные считываются. Существуют ли подобные реализации в частности для линукс?

Comment: Вы хотите в  обе стороны сделать разъем типа папа?

Comment: @KoVadim Без хаба не получится. Как к sd сделать хаб, и можно ли - не знаю. Для SM делалось достаточно просто

Answer (score 2):

Идея интересная, но с данным адаптером не осуществимая. Не важно, под Windows или Linux. Это просто удлинитель. Реализовать подключение к ПК не получится.

В вашем случае проще использовать WiFi SD card. Для прямой передачи данных, правда, возможно, придётся использовать хаки. В 100%-ной возможности такого решения не уверен (вам же видео нужно?), работал только с фото.